# wxCrafter tab is missing in CodeLite

Tags: linux, wxwidgets, codelite, ubuntu-17.04

I installed CodeLite with wxWidgets on Ubuntu 17.04. Tried to go through "Hello World" Tutorial. The problem is, I don't have wxCrafter tab:

[image]

Also, if I open ***Plugins → Manage Plugins...***, nothing is in there:

[image]

How to enable wxCrafter tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably installed CodeLite from the distro repository. On the Debian and Ubuntu repositories, CodeLite is split into two packages:

- codelite
- codelite-plugins

To install CodeLite with all its plugins, you will need to run:

```
apt-get install codelite codelite-plugins
```

wxCrafter is not open sourced, but we do support a package that works with Ubuntu 17.04.

You can get it from here (pick the one that matches Ubuntu 17.04 (zesty) official):
http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/Repositories#toc6

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did all steps and got this error during the installation: 
"dpkg: error processing archive CodeLite-10.0.6-ubuntu-xenial-x86_64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/codelite/wxgui.zip', which is also in package wxcrafter 2.7-1.xenial
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)"

Comment: I have updated my original answer, please follow these steps instead

Comment: Yes, it helped! Thank you so much.